# Hide main-component class in homepage

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I have a template that has the feature to hide front-page component.
Unfortunately setting this feature to "hide" does hide the component but not the wrapper that surrounds it so, i need help to hide it manually in the home page only with id '101'.
The code that uses that feature is below:

```
function setMainContent() {
        global $mainbody_block, $editmode, $side_block, $subnav, $active, $splitmenu_col, $leftcolumn_width, $rightcolumn_width, $mainmod2_width, $frontpage_component, $mainmod3_width;
        $row = 'section-row3';

        $cases = array(
            'case3' => modulesClasses('case3'),
            'case4' => modulesClasses('case4')
        );

        $this->maincontent = '<div id="section-row3" class="section-row"><div id="section-row3-inner">
            <div id="main-body-surround" class="spacer">';

        function mainbody($t, $c) {
                global $mainbody_block, $leftcolumn_width, $mainmod2_width, $editmode, $frontpage_component, $mainmod3_width, $leftcolumn_width, $splitmenu_col, $subnav, $active;

                $tmp = "";

                $tmp .= '<div id="main-body" class="spacing">
                        <div class="module-'.$mainbody_block.'">';

                        $main = '
                            <div id="main-content">';
```

Is the best way to do this with php or css?

Comment: Buddy there are syntax errors. Where are the closing braces for functions

Comment: It exists below but i did not paste it because of the characters limit